# using dispatch group in multi for loop with urlsession tasks

Tags: swift, httprequest, grand-central-dispatch, swift5, urlsession

I have using a dispatch group `wait()` that block my a `for` loop from completing the code until a set of `urlsession` tasks (in  another loop with completion  handler)  to be completed before appending new element to my array

the current code will finish the first loop before the second loop of `urlClass.selectfoodURL` is completed

I want to append the array in meal history after my urlfood for loop is completed 
on of the problem in my approach of using dispatch groups is the `wait()`, when my select food is called the `urlsession` stuck and doesn’t complete with `group.wait`

```
func userSnackHistoryArray() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let Arrays // array of dictionary
    for array in Arrays {

        var generateMeal = MealDetails() // struct type
        do {
            let aa = try JSONDecoder().decode(userSnack.self, from: array)
            generateMeal.names = convertToJsonFile.type

            for name in generateMeal.names!{
                group.enter()

                urlClass.selectfoodURL(foodName: name){ success in
                    generateMeal.units!.append(allVariables.selectedUnit)
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
            // my select food is called but the urlsession stuck and doesnt complete with group.wait is active
            // group.wait()
            mealHistory.append(generateMeal)
        } catch { }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main){
        print("complete")
    }
}
```

I have shortened  my code to focus on the problem ,, I can split my code into two functions and solve the problem , but I want to use only one function
any suggestions or ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than waiting, you should just create a local array of values to be added, and then add them when it’s done:

```
func retrieveSnacks() {
    var snacksToAdd: [Snack] = []

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    ...

    for url in urls {
        group.enter()
        fetchSnack(with: url) { result in
            dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))   // note, I’m assuming that this closure is running on the main queue; if not, dispatch this appending of snacks (and `leave` call) to the main queue

            if case .success(let snack) = result {
                snacksToAdd.append(snack)
            }

            group.leave()
        }
    }

    // when all the `leave` calls are called, only then append the results

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.snacks += snacksToAdd

        // trigger UI update, or whatever, here
    }
}
```

Note, the above does not assure that the objects are added in the original order. If you need that, you can use a dictionary to build the temporary results and then append the results in sorted order:

```
func retrieveSnacks() {
    var snacksToAdd: [URL: Snack] = [:]

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    ...

    for url in urls {
        group.enter()
        fetchSnack(with: url) { result in
            if case .success(let snack) = result {
                snacksToAdd[url] = snack
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        let sortedSnacks = urls.compactMap { snacksToAdd[$0] }
        self.snacks += sortedSnacks

        // trigger UI update, or whatever, here
    }
}
```

Finally, I might suggest adopting a completion handler pattern:

```
func retrieveSnacks(completion: @escaping ([Snack]) -> Void) {
    var snacksToAdd: [URL: Snack] = [:]

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    ...

    for url in urls {
        group.enter()
        fetchSnack(with: url) { result in
            if case .success(let snack) = result {
                snacksToAdd[url] = snack
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        let sortedSnacks = urls.compactMap { snacksToAdd[$0] }
        completion(sortedSnacks)
    }
}

retrieveSnacks { addedSnacks in
    self.snacks += addedSnacks
    // update UI here
}
```

This pattern ensures that you don’t entangle your network-related code with your UI code.

---

I apologize that the above is somewhat refactored from your code snippet, but there wasn’t enough there for me to illustrate what precisely it would look like. But hopefully the above illustrates the pattern and you can see how you’d apply it to your code base. So, don’t get lost in the details, but focus on the basic pattern of building records to be added in a local variable and only update the final results in the `.notify` block.

FWIW, this is the method signature for the method that the above snippets are using to asynchronously fetch the objects in question.

```
func fetchSnack(with url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<Snack, Error>) -> Void) {
    ...

    // if async fetch not successful 

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(.failure(error))
    }

    // if successful

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(.success(snack))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an absolute lifesaver; I was struggling with how to setup the `DispatchGroup` calls cleanly and this is great.